# Java: Parameterised Data Types & Non-Concrete Types

Tags: java, generics, interface

In terms of generics, can parameterised types specify non-concrete types such as abstract classes or interfaces? So for instance, would it be possible to program something like ...

```
ArrayList< SomeInterfaceType > list = new ArrayList< SomeInterfaceType >();
```

... and can the same be said when using a wildcard or a bounded wildcard? For example what if I did something like ...

```
ArrayList< ? >
```

.. or perhaps something like ...

```
public static void foo( ArrayList< ? extends SomeInterfaceType > ) { ... }
```

... would these wildcards be able to accept both concrete and non-concrete types at the same time? And if yes, I presume in the last example, it would also be possible to have the wildcard take an abstract class or interface and still 'extends' from SomeInterfaceType.

Comment: Yes. Why don't you try it out yourself?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I am in the middle of quickly going through some programming material, and thought it would be quicker to receive an answer this way. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jesper Would you like to turn this into an "answer" so that I can accept it as a solution? I would like to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use non-concrete types (such as interface types) as type arguments for a parameterized type.

A simple example would be a `List` of `Runnable` (`Runnable` is an interface):

```
class MyTask implements Runnable { ... }

List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
tasks.add(new MyTask());

// Run all the tasks in the list
for (Runnable task : tasks) {
    task.run();
}
```

Likewise, it works with wildcards.

Comment: Worth noting is the use of `List<Runnable>` rather than `ArrayList<Runnable>`, and that diamonds `<>` require java 7+ language level.

Comment: Thank you for the example, however isn't it true that inheritance relationships are not recognised in this context? For example if I declare ArrayList< Object > list = new ArrayList< Object >(); Then I will not be able to do list.add( new Customer() ); Then how is it possible for the above example to add MyTask objects in place of the Runnable parameterised types?

Comment: @Grateful Yes, you can add a `Customer` to an `ArrayList<Object>` (try it out!).

Comment: @Jesper Okay that distorts my current understanding of generics. Regarding the statement

`public static void processData( ArrayList< Object > data ) { ... }`

I just read in a book that "there is no such thing as inheritance of parameterized types. In other words, even though `Customer` is a subclass of `Object`, this relationship does not apply to `<Customer>` and `<Object>`. This is when the question mark that represents an unknown type becomes handy". This statement seems to contradict what you've just told me.

Comment: @Jesper Please forgive me. I was not trying to be rude. I just genuinely wanted to ensure what I was reading. Any elaborations would be appreciated.

Comment: @Grateful What the book means is that `ArrayList<Customer>` is not a subclass of `ArrayList<Object>`. It means you can't pass an `ArrayList<Customer>` to the `processData` method, because `ArrayList<Customer>` is not a subclass of `ArrayList<Object>`. That doesn't mean that you can't put `Customer` objects in an `ArrayList<Object>`. It's about the subtype relationship between `ArrayList`s themselves, not the objects that you put in the lists.

Comment: OOooooohhh, I see! That was really useful. I appreciate help and patience.